# How to fix Popup width and height to maximum level of the screen depend on Computer resolution

Tags: kendo-ui, popup, kendo-grid, popupwindow, screen-resolution

i am having requirement that kendo popup needs to maximize the height and width of popup to maximum level through out window  depend upon the computer resolution  iam working with kendo popup thank you
**help me out of this**

Answer (score 3):

A possible appoach is to [maximize](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-maximize) popup on the fly in the Grid's [edit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event.

```
  edit: function(e) {$(e.container).data("kendoWindow").maximize();}
```

Also you have to use folowing css

```
.k-edit-form-container {width: auto;}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@hewerrr/eZUnO)